# bootstrap full width element height under row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need an element to take the entire screen's width.

Thus, I put it under `.row` like so because `.container` adds 15 px padding, then `.row` takes it away to be full width again.

```
.container-fluid
  .row
    header  
      .col-xs-12
        "content content content"
```

But when I inspect the header element, its height is 0.

How do I get it to automatically be the height of the contents of `.col-xs-12` without hard-coding the pixel values or using javascript?

Comment: You would not need to you any grid classes at all to make something full width. See the grid examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ note the instructions: No grid classes are necessary for full-width elements. And it's better too, because then there's no padding or negative margin to contend with

Comment: But I want columns in it eventually. And I want it inside container so that it's responsive

Comment: Then it's still not like that. You would use .container-fluid, .row, then the column classes, there's nothing to be the direct child of .row except for the .col-X-X classes, but an easy way to fix this to work is to put a clearfix class on the header

Comment: Yes, also, use .container-fluid as your container class in order to take up the full width of a browser window.

Comment: word. i was using container-fluid. same problem. updated OP

Answer (score 2):

So a few things:

First of all, as per [Bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com), "only columns may be immediate children of rows." If you are going to add a header element, make it a parent element of the .row or the .container, or put it within the .col-xs-12.

All .col-xx-xx divs float left, so they are technically taken out of the page flow, which is why your header element has no height--the browser doesn't see its contents as affecting the flow of the page, so it doesn't believe it has a height. Using Bootstrap, you can add the .clearfix class to fix this, though I suggest making sure that you clean up your Bootstrap layout a bit first.

EDIT:
Also (and I suppose this should go without saying, but since your code is sparse -- and in haml?--, I want to make sure that it's true), if your .col-xs-12 has no content in it yet, you won't have a height because there's no minimum height set on a .col-xx-xx divs.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="header">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                     CONTENT HERE
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you expound on the clearfix? Thanks to your explanation, I understand now why it's height is 0. But if I can't wrap an element between row and col, then how do I make my element full screen width?

Comment: So you don't want to wrap an element between row and col -- that's not how Bootstrap works. I'm going to add code to my response for you.

Comment: I understand. so how do I make it full width? Excellent answer with full profound explanation on why my approach won't work. So i'm looking for an approach that works. =]

Comment: content wasn't the issue. I have content. My intention is to not include code extraneous to the core of the problem

Comment: thanks for the update. The issue with doing that is container-fluid adds 15px padding. so my header won't be full width of the screen.

Comment: making the footer have a class of container-fluid like so `footer.container-fluid` seems to work, but I'll have to test if that will keep my header image or background image responsive

Comment: A .clearfix is a class that's added to most front-end stylesheets to fix the exact problem you came across: the parent element of floating elements doesn't have a height. You can see a great explanation here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I assume you have access to the stylesheets? You can override Bootstrap's default styles by loading your stylesheet below bootstrap.css and just declaring  ".container-fluid {padding: 0;}"

Comment: That would not be a good thing to do, as it would cause the content to be too wide. container fluid ahs padding, row cancels taht padding, and col adds taht padding again. they all need each other.

Comment: Just FYI, using a .row actually fixes the collapsing div problem on its own, without the help of a .clearfix (the creators just built that in, since all its columns are floating) :)

Comment: I'm confused. Didn't you just say that you don't like the padding in the .container-fluid?

Comment: the content being "too wide" means overflowing off the screen width. I want it exactly the screen width. But even if it accomplished the latter, it would still not be good because of the way bs container row col work